# Symfony2-Doctrine Connection to SQL Server 2005

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I try to generate entities based on a database SQL Server 2005 with Doctrine.

Unfortunatly, when i launch my command i have an error :

```
[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

In the folder PHP\etc, drivers are OK.
In the folder (inside the project) vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver, i can see PDOSqlsrv.

Parameters.yml is configured like that :

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
database_host: myHost
database_port: null
database_name: myName
database_user: user
database_password: pwd
```

I don't understand the problem with my configuration.

If anyone has an idea ... thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a doctrine problem, it's rather a PDO's one. It looks like you didn't install the MS SQL [PDO's driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

Comment: Wamp with php 5.4.12 and php.ini has references :
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
    extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

Comment: Since you launch PHP from the command line, it uses a different `php.ini`. Check whether the extension is enabled for the `cli` sapi

Comment: With the command "php --ini" : 

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

You think maybe at an other answer ?

Comment: Ok i see, indeed, he use an other php.ini ... and now my driver are not "An application Win32 valid".I will arrange that. Thanks for help !